# Finding the probability

Tags: probability

The random variable $T$ has a t-distribution with $10$ degrees of freedom. Determine the value of $t$ for which 
$P(|T|>t)=0.1$.

My computation by considering $2-2P(T<t)=0.1$ , I get $t=1.812$ but the book provides $t=3.169 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your result is the correct one. Simple calculation shows that:

$2(1-P(T<1.812))\approx 0.1$ while

$2(1-P(T<3.169))\approx 0.01$, where $T\sim t_{10}$. I suggest you check the assignment once again and if it indeed says 0.1 (=10%) you are good to go on :)

Comment: Thanks for the help I only thought was me misunderstanding the question